# SQL SELECT, CASE, BETWEEN INTO statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, between

I have a SQL query that compares 2 tables to check if login times and schedules are off to populate a 3rd table with an int value. I got it working however I'm trying to add other variations to the select command.

Here is the code that works:

```
DECLARE @sqlSelect varchar(max)
SET @sqlSelect = 'SELECT loginlogout.[Agent Name], case when loginlogout.[Login Time] = Schedules$.StartTime then 0 else 1 end as LoginInc into Integers FROM loginlogout JOIN Schedules$ on loginlogout.[Agent Name] = Schedules$.AgentName'

EXEC(@sqlSelect)
GO
```

What I am trying to add is this:

```
DECLARE @six varchar(max)
DECLARE @sixo varchar(max)
DECLARE @sixnerdy varchar(max) 
DECLARE @sqlSelect varchar(max)
SET @six = '[6:00AM]'
SET @sixo = '[6:05AM]'
SET @sixnerdy = '[6:30AM]' 
SET @sqlSelect = 'SELECT loginlogout.[Agent Name], case when loginlogout.[Login Time] = Schedules$.StartTime then 0 when [Login Time] BETWEEN '+ @sixo +' and '+ @sixnerdy +' then 1 else 1 end as LoginInc into Integers FROM loginlogout JOIN Schedules$ on loginlogout.[Agent Name] = Schedules$.AgentName'

EXEC(@sqlSelect)
GO
```

When running this query I get error msg 207 invalid column name. Hence I tried:

```
SET @sqlSelect = 'SELECT loginlogout.[Agent Name], case when loginlogout.[Login Time] = Schedules$.StartTime then 0 when [Login Time] BETWEEN '+ @sixo +' and '+ @sixnerdy +' then 1 else 1 end as LoginInc into Integers'
```

to remove the FROM statement. This says the command runs however Integers table is never created. Can this be done in 1 SQL command? Also I need to add about 4 more BETWEEN queries to tack onto this command.

Comment: `6:00AM` is an odd field name. Is that really the name of the field?

Comment: @ConradFrix, `6:00AM` is not used as a field name, it's used in the `between`

Comment: @HoneyBadger notice the `[]` around the 6:00AM. Since it's concatenated to sql string I would expect it to be treated as a field name and not a value

Comment: @ConradFrix, you are right, it seems that was the problem.

Comment: There's no need to incur the overhead nor risk of dynamic SQL here, you can just use the dates are parameters for a normal SELECT command.

Comment: When I remove the [] brackets I get the error stating "Incorrect syntax near ':'. " msg 102

Comment: @HoneyBadger maybe. With a name like `Schedules$` it could be an imported spreadsheet that had weird headers

Comment: I don't know, removed my answer, as it clearly was not correct

Comment: @conrad frix, that it was. Excel spreadsheet that was imported.

Comment: @RBarry Young, I'm running dynamic as it was recommended by a colleague. Mainly going off the help he has provided (even though I have run this command with it's simple SELECT command)

Comment: @HoneyBadger I really appreciate your suggestions though. I know theres a way and we're close.

Comment: I am sure there is a way (by the way, even though I deleted the answer, you really should use the table name when referring to a column. But obviously that's not what's going wrong here)

Comment: Try replacing *EXEC(@sqlSelect)* with *PRINT @sqlSelect*.  This will show you the query your batch is creating.  That should make the debugging easier.  I suspect the problem is your BETWEEN doesn't delimit 6:00AM and 6:05AM within single quotes, preventing it from recognising them as text values.

Comment: after the print, "Query executed successfully". It shows, my sqlSelect query essentially.

    SELECT loginlogout.[Agent Name]
,      case 
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] = Schedules$.StartTime then 0 
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN 6:05AM and 6:30AM then 1 
          else 1 
       end as LoginInc 
into Integers 
FROM loginlogout 
JOIN Schedules$ 
  on loginlogout.[Agent Name] = Schedules$.AgentName

Comment: If you run that directly in SSMS do you recieve the desired results?

Comment: @Destination-data, It looks like it was a success, I ran it as a new query and as a raw non-dynamic SQL command. it created the table, and gave integer values.

with this, I may be able to get what I need from it... going to begin testing by adding 3 more between statements as needed.

Comment: Why does it work directly in SSMS rather than a dynamic SQL command?

Answer (score 1):

Initial glance would question that there isn't a problem because the times aren't wrapped in single quotes.  Does something like this work?

```
DECLARE @six varchar(max)
DECLARE @sixo varchar(max)
DECLARE @sixnerdy varchar(max) 
DECLARE @sqlSelect varchar(max)
SET @six = '''6:00AM'''
SET @sixo = '''6:05AM'''
SET @sixnerdy = '''6:30AM''' 
SET @sqlSelect = 'SELECT loginlogout.[Agent Name], case when loginlogout.[Login Time] = Schedules$.StartTime then 0 when [Login Time] BETWEEN '+ @sixo +' and '+ @sixnerdy +' then 1 else 1 end as LoginInc into Integers FROM loginlogout JOIN Schedules$ on loginlogout.[Agent Name] = Schedules$.AgentName'

EXEC(@sqlSelect)
GO
```

Although it all still seems kind of clumsy. Is there a reason to `EXEC` a SQL string vs just executing the `SELECT` statement as-is?